# Return min and max number from range showing as text

Tags: javascript

I need to parse a table with prices range, but I've got stuck because prices range is showing as text only, and there is no id's or classes to identify them.
Text looks like the following thing:

```
11 702 500 - 16 000 000
760 550 - 890 000
145 000 200 - 185 000 100
```

Is it possible to use regex or something to return two values, first as first price and second as second price?
I understand how I can remove spaces, but I have no idea how to divide both numbers and return them individually

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tx4d439m/

Comment: Just `split` 'em : `.text().replace(/\s/g, '').split('-')`

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I need. Could you please write an answer so I can mark this question as solved?

Comment: so for first ex you want to get 11702500 and 16000000 ??

Comment: @OnlyMAJ If I understood correctly, he wants 145000200 and 185000100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var x = '11 702 500 - 16 000 000';
x = x.replace(/\s/g,'').split('-');
console.log(x);
```